# Is it possible to factory-reset an HipChat server?

Tags: hipchat

I want to remove all users, messages, ect but keep the vm settings.

Is it possible to entirely factory-reset an HipChat server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an official way to do this right now. You could try to remove the data from MariaDB, Redis and ElasticSearch and reboot, but it might leave your server in a non-supported state. I would redeploy a fresh OVA/AMI instead.